# Hide or show overlays when zoom out/in

Tags: android, google-maps, overlay, zooming

Is it possible that for zoom level map-view shows overlays. For example when zoom level is 16 show selected overlays and so on?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  See the [zoom_changed event on the map](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map).  Add an event listener, when it fires examine the zoom level and act upon it.

[This map](http://www.geocodezip.com/ParkerPalmSprings.html) hides the labels below zoom level 18.